# Cannot access servlet using Eclipse and Tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I created a new dynamic web project called TestWeb in Eclipse. I added a single index.html to the WebContent folder and created a single web servlet, making the servlet available at /Test.

I can access the index.html file at http://localhost:8080/TestWeb, however, I cannot access the servlet at http://localhost:8080/TestWeb/Test. Please assist.

Here is the code for the Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

}
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>TestWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: share your web.xml as well please

Comment: I shared the web.xml file.

Comment: I am not JEE dev but maybe including info which you get *instead* of what you expected would be helpful for those who can help you. So are you getting any 404 error? Is there any log/stacktrace related to it?

Comment: @Hendré Try changing `@WebServlet("/Test")` to `@WebServlet("TestWeb/Test")`

Comment: @Pshemo I am getting a 404 error with no stack trace.

Comment: @DanielB. I changed the WebServlet as requested. I am still getting a 404 error though.

Comment: How, from inside the UI, are you launching the servlet? From the Servers view, can you right click on your Tomcat instance and choose "Clean Tomcat Work Directory...", and then retry?

Comment: Cleaning the Tomcat Work Directory had no effect. I select the project and click on the Run As button to launch the application. @nitind

Comment: Try it off of the servlet class itself. This isn't an installed copy of Tomcat, is it?

Comment: @nitind I still get a 404 error from the servlet itself. I downloaded the zipped Tomcat archive, extracted it to my home directory and added it as a server in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried adding servlet-mapping tags in your web.xml ?

Comment: The WebServlet annotation is all that is needed to discover the servlet. I have tried mappings without annotation that also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your web.xml (deployment descriptor) file, make sure it has correct xml schema defined in it and if everything is good there then change you annotation like this
@WebServlet("/Test/*")

Comment: I added the web.xml file to the question. Changing to "/Test/*" did not help, I am still getting the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I soled the issue by renaming the project. My project name consisted of two words and one space. "Password Services". Once I renamed the project to "Server" I could reach the servlet.